# How can I create a variable that tracks the total time spent in a Roblox game even after rejoining?

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

how to make a variable that tells the amount of time you stayed in a game, and is stacked everytime you rejoin

the game in question is a roblox game btw. i also plan to make it so that the script gives you those roblox badges if you are in the game for a specific amount of time

i made a variable and used the repeat function, but thats it

Answer (score 1):

I think it's good to use 'os' module to calculate time(executing time).

```
function updateTime()
    local currentTime = os.time()
    timePlayed = timePlayed + (currentTime - startTime)
    startTime = currentTime
end
```

This function calculates and updates play time. Further, you can use(make yourself) compare function to give badges.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need datastores. Roblox has a system to store data even after player leaves the game. I'll link the doc here just incase:
https://create.roblox.com/docs/cloud-services/datastores